# Maui Gui does not react to changed values in the viewmodel

Tags: maui, syncfusion

I got a List in the ViewModel and the UI is not reacting to changes of property values.
It is about the button (SfChip) background colour, which is not updated.
(a selected button is red, all others are white).

Here is the XAML:

```xml
<syncfusion:SfChipGroup ItemsSource="{Binding PageButtonList}" >
    <syncfusion:SfChipGroup.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:PageModel">
            <syncfusion:SfChip Text="{Binding Title}"
                               Background="{Binding IsCurrentPage, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}"
                               TextColor="Black" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </syncfusion:SfChipGroup.ItemTemplate>
</syncfusion:SfChipGroup>
```

The Background color is bound to a `bool` using a `BoolToColorConverter`:

```xml
<toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter" 
               TrueObject="{x:Static Colors.Red}"
               FalseObject="{x:Static Colors.White}"/>
```

The boolean value of `IsCurrentPage` is initially true, so the colour is red. Every time I add a PageModel element to the PageButtonList, I set all `IsCurrentPage` properties to `false`, only the last one is `true`.

```cs
private void UpdatePageButtonList()
{
    foreach (var pageModel in PageButtonList)
    {
        pageModel.IsCurrentPage = pageModel.Id == CurrentPageNumber;
    }
}
```

Even if list entries are gradually added and more SfChip's are displayed, they all remain on red. I can set a breakpoint in the method `UpdatePageButtonList()` and see that `IsCurrentPage` is set to `false` for the first list entries.

Probably the UI does not recognise the change of the property or the converter does not work.

**Why does the SfChip's background colour not turn white?**

```cs
public class PageModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title => (Id + 1).ToString();
        
    public bool IsCurrentPage { get; set; }

    public PageModel(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        IsCurrentPage = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the [documentation of the SfChip control](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/maui/Syncfusion.Maui.Core.SfChip.html) the `BackgroundColor` property is bindable. Have you tried with `BackgroundColor` instead of `Background`?

Comment: @Julian Background is right. The color red is shown. I also tried BackgroundColor, it does not work.

Comment: Is the `IsCurrentPage` property observable? Please show how it is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `IsCurrentPage` property doesn't invoke a `PropertyChanged` event and thus the UI doesn't get notified about the change.

In MAUI, all properties that can change their values and are used in binding expressions that need to update the UI when the value is updated, need to be observable. This applies to ViewModels and Models alike.

When you use a Model class in your ViewModel, e.g. in a `List<PageModel>` or `ObservableCollection<PageModel>` and you bind to a property of said `PageModel`, e.g. `IsCurrentPage`, then this property must be observable.

Make sure that your `PageModel` class implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged), either by doing so manually or by using the Source Generators from the MVVM Community Toolkit:

## Without Source Generators

```cs
public class PageModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }   

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title => (Id + 1).ToString();
    
    private bool _isCurrentPage;
    public bool IsCurrentPage
    { 
        get => _isCurrentPage;
        set
        {
            if(value == _isCurrentPage) return;
            _isCurrentPage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public PageModel(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        IsCurrentPage = true;
    }
}
```

## With Source Generators

```cs
public partial class PageModel : ObservableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title => (Id + 1).ToString();
    
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isCurrentPage; //becomes IsCurrentPage public property

    public PageModel(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        IsCurrentPage = true;
    }
}
```